# Can I travel with 10 days to Expire EU resident permit to Sweden

Tags: schengen, spain, residency, permits

I have a Spanish permanent residence permit and it will expire in 10 days time and I have put in for renewal, the thing is that I want to travel to Sweden for my friend's wedding, is it possible to travel and stay for 3 days and come back to Spain before the permit expires?

Comment: Will you be returning to Spain before the residence permit expires?

Comment: How can it expire if it's permanent? Just sayin' ...

Comment: @hippietrail The word permit was missing but it's not very constructive to make fun of the OP for that.

Comment: I didn't mean to make fun of the OP actually. If anything I was making fun of the name of the permit. Apologies @Blessed if you took it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can travel to Sweden using your residence permit, since you will not be using it after it expires.